# Why do I get a SocketTimeoutException when trying to connect to a RDS PostgreSQL DB in Java?

Tags: java, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have a Spring app I'm trying to get hosted on AWS, and I've been struggling for a few days with the configuration.

I have an EC2 instance and have been able to connect to it with an SSH. I also have a Postgres RDS database set up in AWS, but I haven't been able to connect to it with my code in my IDE, so I haven't yet uploaded the app to the EC2 instance.

I believe the issue is with my security groups, as my `application.properties` appears the way the AWS docs and other guides suggest.

I've been trying to understand the ins and outs of the security group stuff, but it's been a struggle. I assume that it's extremely important to be precise with my SGs in an actual production environment, but I'm trying to use this app only as a demo.

Any loose configuration that allows connectivity to the RDS DB will work for me right now.

`application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://myEndpoint:myPort/myAppName
spring.datasource.username=myDbUsername
spring.datasource.password=myDbPassword
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgresPlusDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
spring.session.store-type=jdbc
spring.session.jdbc.table-name=spring_session
server.servlet.session.timeout=30m
```

I've tried multiple SG configs, here are 2 examples:

---

**RDS config 1**:

```
Public accessibility: Yes
VPC Security Groups: launch-wizard-1 (sg-id-1) / Active
```

`sg-id-1`

```
Inbound rules:
rule 1 -- IP version: IPv4, Type: SSH, Protocol: TCP, Port range: MySSHPort, Source: 0.0.0.0/0
rule 2 -- IP version: IPv4, Type: Custom TCP, Protocol: TCP, Port range: MyLocalPort, Source: 0.0.0.0/0

Outbound rules:
rule 1 -- IP version: IPv4, Type: All traffic, Protocol: All, Port range: All, Destination: 0.0.0.0/0
```

---

**RDS config 2**:

```
Public accessibility: Yes
VPC Security Groups: default (sg-id-2) / Active
```

`sg-id-2`

```
Inbound rules:
rule 1 -- Type: PostgreSQL, Protocol: TCP, Port range: 5432, Source: sg-id
rule 2 -- Type: All traffic, Protocol: All, Port range: All, Source: sg-id

Outbound rules:
rule 1 -- IP version: IPv4, Type: All traffic, Protocol: All, Port range: All, Destination: 0.0.0.0/0
```

---

**When I try to connect with either security group set on the RDS, the connection is timing out with a `SocketTimeoutException`.**

What's causing this?

---

EDIT: It finally connected. The security group configuration that finally allowed access was:

```
Inbound rules:
rule 1 -- Type: PostgreSQL, Protocol: TCP, Port range: 5432, Source: 0.0.0.0/0

Outbound rules:
N/A
```

I also added a subnet route table to the internet gateway, which I believe was necessary, although it initially did not allow access because the source on the SG inbound rule was still incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for the clear question - is the connection string definitely correct? Try to see if it's your Java code or your RDS config by using a regular SQL client - something like [SQL Electron](https://sqlectron.github.io/).

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately didn't have any luck with SQL Electron. I'm pretty sure the connection string is correct. I can't really find any variation from the pattern I used outside of not necessarily including the port on a tutorial or two. I have tried both ways with no luck, and the endpoint I'm using is copied directly from the management console on AWS.

Comment: No worries Stephen - okay set to your 2nd security group config however remove the 1st 5432 rule. Make sure the SG is applied everywhere - can you now connect to it using an SQL client?

Comment: I'm still getting a timeout from both Sqlectron and my IDE.  To be clearr, the default sg-id-2 is applied to the RDS and the EC2 instance and has only one "All traffic" rule for both inbound and outbound. This makes me think I'm doing something wrong with the endpoint. In Sqlectron, I am using the full entry under Endpoint in the RDS management console as the Server Address.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I get confused because when I click the security group from the RDS console, it brings me to the EC2 Management console. Could that mean I don't have a specific security group for my RDS set up? And yes, it is publicly accessible.

Comment: I know so little about all of this that I'm not sure I can verify everything in your last comment without some time, but I will look into it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No worries Stephen, I've now collated some info in an answer, let me know if it doesn't work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**A `SocketTimeoutException` means that your application wasn't able to get a response back from the endpoint, which in this case is the database.**

Something must be wrong with your RDS configuration, here are a few things you can check.

---

**1. Security Group (SG) inbound & outbound rules**

In terms of your SG configuration, security groups are stateful.

This means that if you create an inbound rule allowing in traffic, that traffic is automatically allowed back out regardless of any outbound rules.

As such, the optimal config for a public PostgreSQL RDS DB would be:

```
Inbound rules:
rule 1 -- Type: PostgreSQL, Protocol: TCP, Port range: 5432, Source: 0.0.0.0/0

Outbound rules:
N/A
```

If your inbound rules do not allow PostgreSQL traffic to flow through, your request will never be hitting the database - security groups are applied at the instance level.

---

**2. "Public Accessibility" RDS attribute**

If the security group is set up correctly, double-check that the RDS instance's "Public Accessibility" attribute in "Network & Security" is set to "Yes".

This will assign the RDS instance a public IP address for external access & a public IP address is a requirement for a public database.

---

****3. Subnet type****

If your SGS are fine & your database has a public IP but you don't have an [Internet Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html#d0e22943), it's as though you've bought broadband to connect to the internet but your network cable is unplugged (*lack of an internet gateway*).

For the RDS instance to be accessible publicly, you also need to create an [Internet Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html#d0e22943) in your database's subnet. Once created, you will need to direct internet-bound traffic to the internet gateway.

To do so, set up your subnet's route table to route all data going to `0.0.0.0/0` (internet-bound IPv4 traffic as a destination) to the internet gateway ID (target).

This would make your subnet *public*, as the subnet is now associated with a routing table that has a route to an internet gateway.

[image: architecture diagram for accessing a DB instance in a VPC from the internet]

A public subnet is another requirement for a public database, as this will ensure communication can flow between your VPC & the internet.

**A *private* subnet without an internet gateway, will not allow external access.**

---

**4. DNS hostnames & DNS resolution VPC attributes**

If you *still* cannot access your database publically, make sure that the [DNS hostnames & DNS resolution VPC attributes are enabled](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-dns.html#vpc-dns-updating) for the VPC the RDS instance is in.

---

**5. Network ACLs**

Check that you haven't *created* any [network ACLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html#Rules) in a default state or NACLs with blocking rules, which are associated with the subnet.

Default created NACLs block all inbound and outbound traffic like a firewall regardless of security group settings unless you add rules explicitly allowing them.

Your VPC will come with a default NACL which allows all inbound and outbound IPv4 traffic - use that one.

---

**6. Authentication**

Ensure your username & password / IAM authentication token / Kerberos credentials are 100% correct.

---

The above is a pretty comprehensive list so hopefully, one of the suggestions should allow you to connect to the database externally & rule out your Java code from being incorrect.

You can then make the RDS instance private, only accepting traffic from your EC2 instance(s) security group as well as removing the internet gateway from your subnet to make it private, [applying the security at all layers](https://wa.aws.amazon.com/wellarchitected/2020-07-02T19-33-23/wat.pillar.security.en.html) principle of the security pillar in AWS's Well-Architected Framework.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive list. This was great, and I learned some along the way. Unfortunately, I am still timing out after applying your exact example of an SG, making sure it is publicly accessible, checking that DNS hostnames and resolution are enabled, making sure all ACL rules are the default, and making sure a route table is set up for my internet gateway with the destination 0.0.0.0/0. I am at a loss. It makes me think that I did something bizarre in the setup of the RDS. The only place where I feel I may have something confused is the gateway/routing, which I will detail below.

Comment: I created a new Internet Gateway, but I couldn't attach it as there was already one set up and attached. I decided to set up a route table for that gateway. I created a new route at 0.0.0.0/0 with a target of the gateway that is attached to my VPC. When I attached it, there were 6 possible subnets to associate with, and I checked them all, at least for now. This route's status is active. As I understand it, this is all I had to do!

Comment: Ah I know - the SG I've posted above has source to `sg-id` which I forgot to change from your original post - set the source to `0.0.0.0/0` to allow any IP to connect - does that work? Also - you're not using an IPv6 address to connect, are you? And one final point - if using authentication, username and password is 100% correct? And make sure you have the default NACL rules that come with your VPC as otherwise deleting the rules means *they'll be blocking everything by default*.