# MySQL Workbench connecting to AWS, getting error "unable to connect to localhost"

Tags: amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I have a free tier server on AWS's RDS that I created months ago for a project I've been messing around with. I had set up MySQL Workbench to connect to that instance had previously edited the database through that connection. However, I stopped working on that project and, in an attempt to start working on it again, I opened MySQL Workbench and tried the saved connection, only for it to fail and show the error "Your connection attempt failed for user [my username] to the MySQL server at [my instance's endpoint]:3306: Unable to connect to localhost".

I've checked the connection and I've confirmed that the endpoint is correct, it's using port 3306 as it should, and my login name and password are the same ones I use when I log into AWS directly. I've checked the instance and it reports that it is Available.

It seems like the most common solution for this issue is to check the inbound rules for the instance's security groups and make sure that my machine's ip address is added to it. When I look at that database's inbound rules, I see one, named default, that is set to allow all traffic using any protocol and port. The other is one I added when I initially set up the database and it is set to allow my machine's ip address, obtained using ipconfig. Despite this, I am still getting this error.

Does anyone see what I'm missing here? I can provide more details about my security groups and my database if that would help.

Comment: Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69504845/4800344) which has a few other aspects which you also need to check for any RDS DB - once sure that you do do what my answer says, please update your question and we can then see where the problem still lies :)

Answer (score 1):

After following Ermiya Escandary's instructions (found here: [Why do I get a SocketTimeoutException when trying to connect to a RDS PostgreSQL DB in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69498643/why-do-i-get-a-sockettimeoutexception-when-trying-to-connect-to-a-rds-postgresql/69504845#69504845)), I was able to set up my security groups properly and now it is working. Thanks, Ermiya!