# Unable to connect the server, Timeout Expire to Postgres RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I've had a postgres RDS launched on AWS

1. I have public access enabled
   [image]
2. I also check the security group, inbound rules
   [image]

Things look okay to me, but the issue here is that I cannot connect to the server, I got "unable to connect to the server, timeout expired" with the pgAmin4, using correct endpoint and port

[image]

Trying to debug, I realize when I deploy the postgres on a server (might be a VM), I have to modify the configuration file (pg_hba.conf), so I guess I have to do the same with RDS. Is that true with RDS?

I got the default option group named default:postgres-13, but I cannot modify the option.
Please help for clue.
[image]

Edited: correct a typo

Comment: You don't have to set pg_hba.conf. Your setting looks ok, so some other thing is missing...

Comment: yeah, it is quite simple and straightforward, but haven't yet figure out how come!

Comment: There's a few other things too - check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69504845/4800344) and let me know if that fixes anything

Comment: thank you, I am doubt about the subnet and routable, I put my postgres in a private subnet with the internet gateway attached,  even though I have an EC2 in the same subnet and I can connect without any issues, I still need to check around

Comment: Your group policy shows only IPv4.  Do you know that your client is not using IPv6?

Answer (score 0):

I realize that exposing a RDS to public network never be a good practice. Keep it in a private subnet and use a bastion host inside the VPC to access the database instance.

And, ssh tunneling through the bastion host is considered as a good choice for access from public network.